# Meowing when pooping

Tags: cats, health, defecation

Why does my 2 month old female kitten meow when using the bathroom? She succeeds in using it but cries out in pain before she does.. please help

Comment: If you really think she's in pain, why haven't you taken her to the vet yet?

Comment: Hailey, cats will begin to use the bathroom in odd places as they get more and more desperate to tell you that they are ill. If you don't take her to the vet soon,  you may wake up to poop/urine on your carpet - or your forehead.

Answer (score 8):

She may have a urinary tract infection.  This is curable with antibiotics, possibly (I am not sure) with a shot.    Impacted anal glands are a possibility; the vet can squeeze them clear.  There are other possibilities, but she needs a vet, ASAP.